# KeyboardEvent: detect that a key has a printed representation

Tags: javascript, keydown, onkeydown

In my React/Javascript app, I am listening for [KeyboardEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent). The documentation for the [key property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) is quite clear on how to get the pressed key value:

> Its value is determined as follows:
>
> - If the pressed key has a printed representation, the returned value is a non-empty Unicode character string containing the printable representation of the key.
> - If the pressed key is a Space key, the returned value is a single space
> - If the pressed key is a control or special character, the returned value is one of the [pre-defined key values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values).

I want to test that the pressed key has a printed representation or is a Space. i.e. it is NOT one of the pre-defined key values.

I could not find a `hasPrintedRepresentation` property. Should I write my own `hasPrintedRepresentation()` that tests and excludes each one of those 400-or-so pre-defined key values before returning `true`? I could not find a library that already does this grunt work. Did I miss something? Thank you!

Comment: Are there printable keys that would result in an output of more than one Unicode character? If not, checking the length of the returned value could be an easy start (or easier, if you still had some possible multi-character return values, that would need checking separately), because all the pre-defined key values appear to be at least two characters in length (`FN`, resp. `Fx` with `x` for a specific function key, appear to be the shortest ones on that list.) And that a key for a non-printable character gets added in the future with a length less than two, is also highly unlikely, I suppose.

Comment: I totally missed this simple solution. Yes it makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `key` property of the KeyboardEvent object to get the pressed key value.

You could use the `Object.hasOwn()` method in JavaScript to check if the `key` property of the KeyboardEvent object has a printed representation or is a Space. The `Object.hasOwn()` method returns `true` if the specified object has the indicated property as its own property. If the property is inherited, or does not exist, the method returns `false`.

Here's an example of how you could use the `Object.hasOwn()` method to test if the pressed key has a printed representation or is a Space:

```js
function hasPrintedRepresentation(event) {
  const key = event.key;
  return Object.hasOwn(key, 'length') && key.length === 1 || key === ' ';
}
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer. Although as I'm using typescript, it already guarantees that `key` is a string. So my test is just `key.length === 1 || key === ' '`